# import vs from import in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

why does '`from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer as si`' works but '

```
import sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer as si'
```

do not work

I want to know, why this won't work. I am new to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is the way the Python import statement works. The first import statement imports the `SimpleImputer` class from the `sklearn.impute` module and then names it `si`. The second import statement tries to import a module named `SimpleImputer` from a module named `sklearn.impute`. This does not work because in Python, the import statement only allows you to import modules, not submodules.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use import with modules.

with `from ... import ...` you can import variables so submodules, functions, classes, and everything else.

As SimpleImputer is not a module only the second option is availiable.

---

Writen a bit differently import only works in general with files, from ... import works with variables declared in the script.